# Pass Model to column ClientTemplate editor in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid whereas the columns are defined as:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(b => b.Field);
    columns.Bound(b => b.OldValue);
    columns.Bound(b => b.NewValue);
    columns.Bound(b => b.DateImported).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}");
    columns.Bound(b => b.BuildingChangeValidationStatusType).ClientTemplate("#=BuildingChangeValidationStatusType.Value#").Width(250);
    columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Update").Click("updateValidation"));
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(172);
})
```

The BuildingChangeValidationStatusType client template is defined as:

```
@model Rep.Models.BuildingChangeValidationViewModel
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("BuildingChangeValidationStatusType") // Name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Value")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model.BuildingChangeValidationStatuses)
)
```

I'm wondering how I might pass the model for the Grid to the client template so that the line:

```
.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model.BuildingChangeValidationStatuses)
)
```

would resolve properly. Any ideas?

Comment: this might not be helpful but my suggestion is to use foreignkey as it seems to be a dropdownlist in the grid edit mode

Comment: Roti, won't work. The list is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it a different way by passing the data I needed to the DropdownList in the client template via a javascript function.  So the client template containing the dropdown is as so:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("BuildingChangeValidationStatusType") // Name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property
    .DataValueField("Id") 
    .DataTextField("Value")
    //.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model.BuildingChangeValidationStatuses)
        .DataSource(
            source => source.Read(read =>
                    read.Action("BuildingValidationLookups_Read", "Plan").Data("getBuildingId")
             )
             .ServerFiltering(true)
        )
        .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

Notice the data source read action, it invokes the method on my "Plan" controller named: "BuildingValidationLookups_Read", but also passes the data retrieved from the "getBuildingId" javascript function which is defined as:

function getBuildingId() {

```
var entityGrid = $("#BuildingValidationGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var selected = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());
return {
    buildingId: selected.BuildingId
};
```

}

My controller method is defined as:

```
   public JsonResult BuildingValidationLookups_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int buildingId)
    {
        return Json(PopulateBuildingChangeValidationTypes(buildingId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

All is well now.